# Broken services (systemd-modules-load.service +..) after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: systemd, ureadahead

Just updated my server from 16.04 up to 22.04 one step at a time. Now I have these problems that are way beyond me.  The machine is still working. How can I fix these broken services? Or can I somehow remove them if they redundant?

```
$ sudo systemctl list-units --failed
  UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                   
● systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules
● ureadahead.service           loaded failed failed Read required files in advance
● user@123.service             loaded failed failed User Manager for UID 123

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
3 loaded units listed.
$
$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
× systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-08-20 13:33:48 BST; 7min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
             man:modules-load.d(5)
    Process: 18564 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 18564 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 9ms

Aug 20 13:33:48 bertha systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Aug 20 13:33:48 bertha systemd-modules-load[18564]: Failed to insert module 'it87': Device or resource busy
Aug 20 13:33:48 bertha systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 20 13:33:48 bertha systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 20 13:33:48 bertha systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
$
$ systemctl status ureadahead.service
× ureadahead.service - Read required files in advance
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ureadahead.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-08-20 12:53:59 BST; 47min ago
   Main PID: 275 (code=exited, status=5)
        CPU: 7ms

Aug 20 12:53:59 bertha systemd[1]: ureadahead.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
Aug 20 12:54:02 bertha ureadahead[275]: ureadahead: Error while tracing: No such file or directory
Aug 20 12:53:59 bertha systemd[1]: ureadahead.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Notice: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
$
$ systemctl status user@123.service
× user@123.service - User Manager for UID 123
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
             └─10-oomd-user-service-defaults.conf, timeout.conf
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2022-08-20 12:57:44 BST; 44min ago
       Docs: man:user@.service(5)
   Main PID: 943 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Startup finished in 1min 5.193s."
        CPU: 2.187s

Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Killing process 1294 (gmain) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Killing process 1295 (gdbus) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Killing process 1296 (dconf worker) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Killing process 1297 (pool-tracker-mi) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Killing process 1293 (tracker-miner-f) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Unit process 1293 (tracker-miner-f) remains running after unit stopped.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 123.
Aug 20 12:57:44 bertha systemd[1]: user@123.service: Consumed 2.185s CPU time.
$
```

Some info about the system..

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM, P5LD2-VM Mainboard
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM, P5LD2-VM Mainboard
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM, P5LD2-VM Mainboard
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM, P5LD2-VM Mainboard
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM, P5LD2-VM Mainboard
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: intel_rng, lpc_ich, leds_ss4200
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5B-MX/WiFi-AP, P5KPL-VM Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785/P7P55 Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
$
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I fix these broken services? Or can I somehow remove them if they redundant?

Answer (score 0):

As a general methodology, these issues are fixed the same way you reportedly got to this point: "one step at a time".

Let's pick an error message from your log: "Failed to insert module 'it87': Device or resource busy". The first Google result is https://github.com/a1wong/it87/issues/1 with a similar title in a repository for this device. Good sign. You could follow that thread and there are different suggestions, the one that worked for their case was as follow:

> my case was solved by adding in grub config `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

This solution is supported by further comments on that source.

If this noesn't work, you need to continue digging. If works for you, you can move on to fix the next error.

Comment: The suggestions in that post didn't turn up anything useful. In the end I just commented out it87 from /etc/modules - now the systemd-modules-load service is happy, without worrying warnings. I don't really need to see the fan speed anyway.
For the ureadahead service, seems many people believe it's not longer necessary so I just did `apt purge ureadahead`  Anyway, thanks for replying